# What would the changes be to a planet tilted to its side?

Tags: planets, environment, axial-tilt

In my previous question I asked how a planet could be tilted unto its side. Now I'm wondering what all of the effects on such a planet would be. Let's assume its a rocky, terrestrial planet like Earth with oceans and shifting continents. I know the ice cap facing the star would be gone and maybe a storm in its place. (I'm not sure when in its timeline this event happens, but let's start with something) The star for this planet could be like ours so no flares to worry about.

Comment: What do you mean by "the ice cap facing the star"? If the planet is tidally locked to its star so that one side of the planet is always lit and the other always dark, then it's axial inclination is by necessity quite small -- not "tilted to its side". If the planet is "tilted to its side" then all parts of the planet will be sometimes lit and sometimes dark.

Comment: The poles of a planet are aligned along the general coordinates of space, NOT towards, away from, or alongside its sun. During the year, it will have one pole pointed towards the sun, then pointed in the direction of the planet's orbit, then pointed away from the sun, then pointed backwards in its orbit, and then back to pointing towards the sun. This is what causes the seasons on our planet. Even if a planet with an axial tilt is tidally locked, its face towards the sun will 'wobble' up and down, alternately having the south and the north pole pointing toward the sun.

Answer (score 0):

the earth is actually tilted(whether or not it's facing the sun depends on the time of year) about 23*, so that might be a good starting point for research, but if you mean like the planetary rotation is completely perpendicular to earth and the north pole is always facing the sun, then you have some differences.

for one, there is day *or* night, not both. if you're in the northern hemisphere, there is no night because you are always facing the sun. the southern hemisphere is always night. I'd guess the southern hemisphere would be colder and have more ice and always the starry night sky, and mostly be a icey wasteland. The north would be more diverse like the earth we live on, with your deserts, rain forests, farmland, etc.

the equator would become a sort of twilight zone(oooh, scary) where it's not quite frozen wasteland and not quite rainforest. probably with smaller plant life, and a bit colder

Comment: Earth's axis of rotation is tilted about 23° 26′ with respect to its orbital plane. (Hint: that's why the tropics are at 23° 26′ latitude north and south, and the polar circles are at 90° − 23° 26′ = 66° 34′ latitude north and south.)

Comment: @AlexP, thanks, I'll change that.